# Unwanted scrolling with jQuery Buttonset

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button, scroll

jQuery UI buttons/buttonsets are giving me fits. I have searched this site for answers, and still do not have a an answer that works well.  I am using jQuery rev 1.11.1 and jQuery UI rev 1.9.2.

I have a buttonset of three buttons that my users click to choose 1 of 3 color themes available for use on their website.  Once they click the button, I show a sample website banner with the selected color theme to the right of the button set.   So I am basically swapping out an image based on their selection.

### Relevant HTML:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 275px;">
    <label for="radio">Your Club Website Color Theme</label>
    <div id="colortheme">
        <input type="radio" style="float:left;" id="colortheme1" name="colortheme" value="1" {{ct1}} ><label for="colortheme1">Theme 1</label>
        <input type="radio" style="float:left;" id="colortheme2" name="colortheme" value="2" {{ct2}} ><label for="colortheme2">Theme 2</label>
        <input type="radio" style="float:left;" id="colortheme3" name="colortheme" value="3" {{ct3}} ><label for="colortheme3">Theme 3</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:300px;">
    <img id="bannerSample" src="/images/club{{BannerTheme}}.jpg" style="max-width:100%">
</div>
```

### Relevant Javascript:

```
jQuery("#colortheme input:radio").click(function(e){
   me.$form.hide(); 
   jQuery("#bannerSample").attr('src','/images/club'+this.value+'.jpg'); 
   me.$form.show();
});
```

---

Note: {{ct1}}, {{ct2}}, & {{ct3} are patched in by the Perl server code; me.$form is just a jQuery object for the form set above the code snippet above.  This buttonset is located in a tab panel inside a jQuery UI dialog.  The problem is that I am getting unintended scrolling down in the dialog when I click one of the buttons in the button set.  *I have tried all the usual solutions, e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), return false, .on(), etc., based on research on this and other websites.*  Cannot find the right solution or combination to stop the unwanted scroll.  The above is the best thing I could come up with.  It still scrolls down on the first click, but after that, it just flashes as it updates the image.

*Can anyone recommend a better approach?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue for me was caused by a conflict in css. Specifically the class 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' has a position of absolute which for some reason causes the scrolling behavior.

I chose to create a more specific rule in my own stylesheet to supercede the default jquery-ui css:

```
.ui-buttonset .ui-helper-hidden-accessible{
    position:relative;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use display:none but I wasn't sure if that would have unintended consequences in other browsers.  I chose this route rather than rewriting the jquery-ui rule because I wasn't sure if there were specific use cases for other ui elements where a position of absolute will be needed and I didn't want to have to remember not to overwrite the css if I update.

I figured this out through a wordpress bug ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23684 although it should be noted that I am not working on a wordpress site so the solution posed is independent.